# AMP HTML: How do you setup 'swipe pagination'?

Tags: pagination, amp-html

I would like to setup an AMP HTML web site that is paginated like a book. Naturally, in addition to having the ability to click/tap left/right arrows, I would like to offer the ability for the reader to swipe back and forth.

I considered the idea of using amp-carousel but then I would need to pre-load every single page, correct? So, what is the alternative? I discovered that in general, I could use JQuery, but how can I incorporate this within AMP HTML?

Thanks in advance!
Keith

Comment: @JohnWhite: P.SE doesn't accept broad questions any more than SO does! It's still a Q&A.

Comment: @John: Here's a good reference: [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/17853) However, I will say that you're probably not too far off.

Comment: You can try to use amp-carousel with type "slides". It will look good. But what are your "pages of the book"? If it's an image you don't need to pre-load them since there is built-in lazy-load functionality. But if it's full of html then yes, you have to pre-load it all. And no, you cann't put jQuery in it as well as any other JavaScript scripts. AMP is all about light-weight HTML pages with some core built-in functionality.